# Add collaborator to many repositories at once

Tags: github

We have 150+ repositories on our GitHub, for different clients. My employer hired new employee to take care of the managed services process and they need access to all the repositories. Inviting them as a collaborator to all repositories one by one is a very time consuming task,

Is there a way to add them to all repositories at once?

Answer (score 1):

If those GitHub repositories were all part of the same organisation, that would be easy: see "[Inviting users to join your organization](https://help.github.com/articles/inviting-users-to-join-your-organization/)"

If not, you can script that with the [GitHub API](https://developer.github.com/v3/):

- [list all your repositories](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#list-your-repositories)
- for eeach repo, [add your collaborator to it](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/collaborators/#add-user-as-a-collaborator).